# ActionLink contains current parameters when route matches

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a the following controller containing one action with a single parameter:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
  public ActionResult Index(int? param)
  {
    return View();
  }
}
```

My MasterPage contains an ActionLink which should point to '/Home/Index':

```
Html.ActionLink("MyActionLinkText", "Index", "Home")
```

Now I add a route like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
  "MyRoute",
  "Home/Something/{param}",
  new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" },
  new { param = "\\d+" });
```

When I navigate to '/Home/Index' the ActionLink points to '/Home/Index'. That's OK.
But when I navigate to 'Home/Something/123' the ActionLink also points to 'Home/Something/123'.

I would understand that behaviour if I generated the ActionLink this way:

```
Html.ActionLink("test", "Index", "Home", new { param = 123 }, null)
```

But since I don't supply any route values, I don't understand that behaviour.

What do I have to do, to let the ActionLink always point to '/Home/Index', indepently from the current parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to add a more specific route for the "Index/Home" case. Something like this will probably do the trick (add it before your own "MyRoute" route, otherwise it won't be picked up):

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "MyRouteNoParam",
    "Home/Index",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
```

Answer (score 1):

I used an empty route variable

```
Html.ActionLink("MyActionLinkText", "Index", "Home", new {param = ""})
```